# How to use QML to import a CSV to s SQLite database?

Tags: sqlite, csv, qml

I've been programming an app that uses two databases, one of which contains contacts that I've exported from outlook.

I would like to import these into a sqlite database using QML/javascript only.

I have created the table and I'm trying to execute the below commands:

```
function createTable(database)
{
    database.transaction(
       function(tx) {
           tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS staff(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "First Name" TEXT, "Last Name" TEXT)');
           tx.executeSql('.mode csv');
           tx.executeSql('".import" "./contacts.csv"');
       }
    )
}
```

I haven't got to the .import yet so that is secondary. I'm guessing I must be missing some method that I'm not familiar with.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the issue you are having?

Comment: I receive this error:

 Error: near ".": syntax error Unable to execute statement

Comment: please add your error to the question as opposed to a comment.  i don't know the answer, i'm just trying to help you get the help you need